# Why is form submitted 2 times Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a form with `onsubmit` event:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'order',
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'validation-wizard wizard-circle form-horizontal',
        'onsubmit' => 'checkStorageField()'
    ],
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
]); ?>
```

And the function which the event triggers is :

```
function checkStorageField(){
    alert(123)
    return false
}
```

But it seems that the event `onsubmit` is triggered 2 times because I get 2 alert on after another and the form is submitted anyway. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [events of ActiveForm](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/#using-events)

for example:

```
$('#order').on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {
    alert(123);
    return false;
});
```